# Printing Arabic on receipt printer using jpos

Tags: printing, arabic

I am trying to print Arabic characters on a receipt using jpos.  I send the proper string to the printer but only question marks are being printed.

Does anyone have experience with printing Arabic characters using jpos?  If so, do you have any pointers for me.
Many Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Code Samples? Printer manufacturer, model... Not really giving us much to work with here...

Comment: The printer is a Touch Dynamic LK-T21.  The application is written in java.  I can see that I am sending the correct character to the POSPrinterControl15.printNormal method.

Comment: Does the printer support Arabic?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on the Touch Dynamic.  But, I now have an Epson TM-T88V and I know that it will print the characters.  I just can't find out how to properly send them to the printer using jpos

Comment: The Epson TM-T88V will not in fact print the desired characters.  I found out that the TM-T88VM will but it must be ordered and the code page with the desired character set must be specified at the time of order.  For a temporary solution, I print bitmaps that contain the desired text. This will hold me over until I receive the multi-lingual printer.